# Assert not returning strict Equal

Tags: javascript, node.js, tdd

I am doing this [tutorial](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001808/ch02.html#I_sect12_d1e1886)

The tutorial thus far shows how to make a simple web server and write a simple test for it using Node.js

The problem I am having seems fairly trivial. The tutorial is using an outdated version of express, and with it, an outdated version of body parser.
To alleviate this, I NPM installed body-parser locally and set the middleware argument to the post method to use body-parsers urlencoded method.

**Index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express(),
    tweets = [];

app.listen(8000)

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Welcome to Node Twitter');
});

app.post('/send', urlencodedParser function(req, res) {
    if(req.body && req.body.tweet) {
        tweets.push(req.body.tweet);
        res.send({status:"ok", message:"Tweet received"});
    } else {
        //no tweet?
        res.send({status:"nok", message:"No tweet received"});
    }
})

app.get('/tweets', function(req, res) {
    res.send(tweets);
})
```

and

**test.js**

```
var http = require('http'),
    assert = require('assert'),
    bodyParser;

var opts = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8000,
    path: '/send',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}

var req = http.request(opts, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    var data = ""
    res.on('data', function(d) {
        data += d
    })

    res.on('end', function() {
        assert.strictEqual(data, '{status:"ok", message:"Tweet received"}' )
    })
})

req.write('tweet=test');
req.end();
```

However, when i run the test, i get:

```
assert.js:89
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
  ^
 AssertionError: '{"status":"ok","message":"Tweet received"}' === '{status:"ok",
 message:"Tweet received"}'
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\workspace\node-demo\test.js:22:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:437:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:351:17)
```

I know most of this is useless. The part that trips me up though, is

```
 AssertionError: '{"status":"ok","message":"Tweet received"}' === '{status:"ok",
 message:"Tweet received"}'
```

According to [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#extended), if I set the 'extended' option to true, I get access "..for rich objects and arrays to be encoded into the URL-encoded format..".

My question is this: Why is my test.js request not returning a strict equal even though the test http request has a content type of 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the answer was to surround my objects keys in strict assert from:

```
assert.strictEqual(data, '{status:"ok", message:"Tweet received"}' )
```

to

```
assert.strictEqual(data, '{"status":"ok","message":"Tweet received"}' )
```

notice quotes around "status" and "message".

Comment: For your information: this is true because JSON requires quotes around object keys.

Comment: @MikeC Thanks for the advice! I must have been confusing the rules between json and string type in my head